# Передача значения элемента через ссылку

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть код:

```
<select class="padding2" name="int">
    <option value="месяц" selected>месяц</option>
    <option value="неделя">неделя</option>
    <option value="день">день</option>
</select>
```

есть ссылка, которая ссылается на эту же страницу `<a href="?page=mygraf">x</a>`/Все это уже обрамлено `<form>`
Мне необходимо, чтобы при клике по ссылке, во внешний php обработчик,
 подключенный в самом начале,

```
    `function get_manager(){ if($_POST['int']=="месяц")
{ $a=$_POST['int'];
$strSql="....".$a."..";       
}else if($_POST['int']=="неделя"){  
$strSql="....".$a."..";               
}`
```

передалось значение выбранного элемента.
Подскажите, как это реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Код обработчика добавьте

Comment: Так сделай ссылку ввиде кнопки, а у формы поставь метод GET и экшн на алрес с этой ссылки.

Comment: Это `?page=mygraf` `GET` Параметр, может тебе нужно не `$_POST` а `GET` взять?

Comment: Точно, что то затупил. Спасибо.